# How to assert/introspect nested recursive structures/enums?

Tags: data-structures, rust, enums, nested

I have a directed graph data structure and I find myself fighting pattern matching to do simple introspection. Is there some better way?

My structure allows multiple parents in addition to multiple children:

```
pub enum NodePtr {
    Terminal(i32),
    Node(Rc<RefCell<Node>>),
}

pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<NodePtr>,
    parents: Vec<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
```

This is the simplest code I can devise to assert a single parent-child relationship has been built up as expected:

```rust
fn example(parent: NodePtr, child: NodePtr) {
    if let NodePtr::Node(parent_rc) = &parent {
        if let NodePtr::Node(child_rc) = &child {
            assert_eq!(parent_rc.borrow().children.len(), 1);
            if let Option::Some(node_ptr) = parent_rc.borrow().children.get(0) {
                if let NodePtr::Node(rc) = node_ptr {
                    assert!(Rc::ptr_eq(rc, child_rc));
                } else {
                    assert!(false);
                }
            } else {
                assert!(false);
            }

            assert_eq!(child_rc.borrow().parents.len(), 1);
            if let Option::Some(weak) = child_rc.borrow().parents.get(0) {
                if let Some(rc) = weak.upgrade() {
                    assert!(Rc::ptr_eq(&rc, parent_rc));
                } else {
                    assert!(false);
                }
            } else {
                assert!(false);
            }
        } else {
            assert!(false);
        }
    } else {
        assert!(false)
    };
}
```

[Full working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2dc837884d8b83a3c73ec2127ec5c314)

It feels like I have to wade through so much matching to get at what I want.  Am I missing some better way or perhaps a different way of thinking?

Comment: Most of your code consists of closed braces and `assert!(false)`. Can you show another example of what you're doing that you consider lacking in elegance/ergonomy? Also note that you can spell `Option::Some` as just  `Some`.

Comment: If you use `Option::unwrap` and make an `unwrapNode`, all of this would be dramatically less nested: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecebc5e695200dda0f57fcd52a22c23f

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for -- thank you -- is it typical to create these sorts of helper functions for when you know what to expect?

Comment: @user4815162342 _Most of your code consists of closed braces and assert!(false)_ that's kinda the point -- I'm asking how to simplify the code

Comment: @prior Fair enough. What I was trying to say was that ways to simplify that particular function might apply to other code that deals with the graph. Or are you saying that doing _anything_ with the graph requires a similar abundance of `assert!(false)` checks?

Comment: @user4815162342 -- It's true that doing anything with the graph has a lot of similar matching going on, but now that I feel more free to create helper functions like loganfsmyth suggests it should make things a lot nicer.  It just felt dirty somehow to create the helper function to get at the enum/struct value I already know is there, but I suppose no more dirty than all the if-let-elses.  DRYing that up is definitely a win.

Comment: @prior Agreed; I've now posted an answer which shows an (IMHO) cleaner helper function which doesn't itself panic, but returns an Option that then provides `unwrap()` when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It feels like I have to wade through so much matching to get at what I want. Am I missing some better way or perhaps a different way of thinking?

You can abstract trivial pattern matching behind a utility function such as:

```
impl NodePtr {
    /// Returns Some if NodePtr is a Node, None otherwise.
    fn as_node(&self) -> Option<&Rc<RefCell<Node>>> {
        match self {
            NodePtr::Node(rc) => Some(rc),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to replace `if let NodePtr::Node(foo) = foo { ... } else { assert!(false); }` with `let foo = foo.as_node().unwrap()`. You can also use `foo.unwrap()` instead of the whole `if let Some(foo) = foo { ... } else { assert!(false); }` block. Finally, you don't need to pattern-match over `x.get(n)`, you can use `x[n]` or `&x[n]`.

Applying all these compresses your code to something as short as:

```
// prove parent & child relationship
let parent_rc = parent.as_node().unwrap();
let child_rc = child.as_node().unwrap();
assert_eq!(parent_rc.borrow().children.len(), 1);
let node_ptr = &parent_rc.borrow().children[0];
assert!(Rc::ptr_eq(node_ptr.as_node().unwrap(), child_rc));
assert_eq!(child_rc.borrow().parents.len(), 1);
let weak = &child_rc.borrow().parents[0];
assert!(Rc::ptr_eq(&weak.upgrade().unwrap(), parent_rc));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e41497773b6ef77aed22c19587f96ac0)

There is a separate question of whether your types could be structured to avoid so much run-time checking and possibility of panics. I would advise looking into existing crates for building DAGs.

Comment: Agreed -- this is a little nicer than @loganfsmyth's answer in the comments since it avoids the panic until the last possible moment giving the choice to the outside caller to use `.unwrap()` or not as they wish.